# How to make css into if statement

Tags: jquery

I want to make if `margin-left` is `900px` click method to DISABLE, I tried everything what I could but not nothing works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var img = $("img");

                $('.aa').click(function(){
                    img.animate({ marginLeft: '-=900px'}, 700) })


                $('.uu').click(function(){
                    img.animate({ marginLeft: '+=900px'}, 700) })
                    if(img.css('margin-left') == '900px'){
                        // I want click to be disabled if margin-left hits 900px
                    }
                })
```

```
<div id="slide">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide"><img src="image1.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="image2.jpg" alt=""></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="image3.jpg" alt=""></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is img? can you please show the full code? what is your aim with `alert = 'hello'`? OP needs to be updated with more details.

Comment: fixed everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still unclear what are you asking soI will provide the steps to achieve. I used your logic, i.e. when it must be disabled, you can change it if you like

In the below example:

- If you click Right button twice, it will be disbled based on the condition. You can change the condition to work as expected.
- I have also provided the in comment, how to remove disabled attribute from a button `$('.uu').removeAttr('disabled')`
- This code will animate all the images, if you want to grab a single image, assign `id` to image, and use that selector to animate.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $("img");

  $('.aa').click(function() {
    img.animate({
      marginLeft: '-=900px'
    }, 700)
  });

  $('.uu').click(function() {
    img.animate({
      marginLeft: '+=900px'
    }, 700);
    if (img.css('margin-left') == '900px') {
      $('.uu').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      //$('.uu').removeAttr('disabled')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slide">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></li>
    <li class="slide"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt=""></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class='aa'>Left</button>
<button class='uu'>Right</button>
```

Comment: I'm making a slider with 3 photos in it, when i click `aa`  more than 3 times all the images will dissapear so i want `aa` to disable click when it will be on third image same on first image

Comment: @LevanCharuashvili Is your question answered?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$('.uu').click(function(){
                    img.animate({ marginLeft: '+=900px'}, 700) })
                    if(img.css('margin-left') == '900px')){
                        alert="hello";
                    }
                })
```